# Make image change with selecting different option in dropdown - Javascript / Html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, if-statement

I have a system where you are able to choose a car. You can then choose the transmission and color. Different cars and transmissions bring up different colors. Not sure how to make an image appear of a car when a color is chosen. So for example I choose the rs6 and automatic and then the black color. I would then want an image to appear depending on the color chosen. How would I program it so different cars and colors bring up different images. Im relatively new to coding. Any help would be aprreciated.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
<form name="CarConfigurator">
    <select id="car" name="Car_make">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Which car?</option>
        <option value="car1">Audi RS6</option>
        <option value="car2">BMW M4</option>
        <option value="car3">Mercedes C63 AMG</option>
        </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <select id="trans" name="A_M">
        <option value="" selected="selected">What trans?</option>
        <option value="auto">Automatic</option>
        <option value="man">Manual</option>
        </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <select id="color" name="Color">
        <option value="" selected="selected">What Color?</option>
         <option value="black">Black</option>
         <option value="blue">Blue</option>
         <option value="red">Red</option>
         <option value="white">White</option>
         <option value="green">Green</option>
         </select>
 </form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1  /jquery.min.js"/
</script>
<script src="configurator.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
$("#car").change(function () {
transmission();
});

$("#trans").change(function () {
transmission();
});

function transmission() {
if ($("#car").val() == "car1" && $("#trans").val() == "auto") {
    $("option[value$='red']").hide();
    $("option[value$='white']").hide();
    $("option[value$='green']").hide();
} else {
    $("option[value$='red']").show();
    $("option[value$='white']").show();
    $("option[value$='green']").show();
}
}
```

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @nyedidikeke   He did't ask to recommend tutorial and has included all the relevant code. Please don't flag the question if you don't know a short answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now it is only working for `Audi - Automatic - black and blue` to show you the basic idea but it is repeating code and you can do the same for the rest of the cars too.

In this example I am setting the `src` of the image as the car selected. For example if you select `car1` and `man` and `red` then `src` of the image as `car1manred.jpg`, also I'm changing the `alt` attribute as well so that you can see the change.

you have to do a lot of manual work. I have created an object for the data that will determine how many cars you have in each category. It would be better if you use `JSON` for that.

Also I have made `car1autoblack` (which gets the src of the images) as an array but you can make it as an object and include other things about the cars in this category. for example `name`, `price`, `availability` and much more

```js
$("#car").change(function () {
transmission();
  selection();
});

$("#trans").change(function () {
transmission();
  selection();
});

$("#color").change(function () {
  selection();
});

var cars = {
  car1autoblack:["car1auto1black1.png","car1auto1black2.jpg"],
  car1autoblue:["car1auto1blue1.png","car1auto1blue2.jpg","car1auto1blue3.jpeg"]
}

function transmission() {
if ($("#car").val() == "car1" && $("#trans").val() == "auto") {
    $("option[value$='red']").hide();
    $("option[value$='white']").hide();
    $("option[value$='green']").hide();
} else {
    $("option[value$='red']").show();
    $("option[value$='white']").show();
    $("option[value$='green']").show();
}
}

function selection(){
  if ($("#car").val() && $("#trans").val() &&         $("#color").val()) {
    var carVal = $("#car").val();
    var transVal = $("#trans").val();
    var colorVal = $("#color").val();
    var combineVal = carVal+transVal+colorVal;
    //var imageLink = combineVal+".jpg";
    //$("#showImg").attr("src", imageLink);
    //$("#showImg").attr("alt", imageLink);
    //console.log(cars[combineVal]);
    var inputDivHTML = "";
    var car = cars[combineVal];
    for(i in car){
      inputDivHTML += "<img class='showImg' src='"+car[i]+"' alt='"+car[i]+"'/>"; 
    }
    $(".imageHere").html(inputDivHTML);
  }
}
```

```css
img.showImg{
  width:150px;
  height:70px;
  margin:10px 3px;
  border:1px solid red;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="CarConfigurator">
    <select id="car" name="Car_make">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Which car?</option>
        <option value="car1">Audi RS6</option>
        <option value="car2">BMW M4</option>
        <option value="car3">Mercedes C63 AMG</option>
        </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <select id="trans" name="A_M">
        <option value="" selected="selected">What trans?</option>
        <option value="auto">Automatic</option>
        <option value="man">Manual</option>
        </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <select id="color" name="Color">
        <option value="" selected="selected">What Color?</option>
         <option value="black">Black</option>
         <option value="blue">Blue</option>
         <option value="red">Red</option>
         <option value="white">White</option>
         <option value="green">Green</option>
         </select>
 </form>
<div class="imageHere">
  <img class="showImg" src="http://www.chinabuddhismencyclopedia.com/en/images/thumb/b/b8/Nature.jpg/240px-Nature.jpg"/>
  <img class="showImg" src="http://www.chinabuddhismencyclopedia.com/en/images/thumb/b/b8/Nature.jpg/240px-Nature.jpg"/>
  <img class="showImg" src="http://www.chinabuddhismencyclopedia.com/en/images/thumb/b/b8/Nature.jpg/240px-Nature.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sorry but could you clarify how I would make different images appear for different settings. From the code the function is only applied to the id "showImg". So what would I do for more images. Thanks again

Comment: ok, I think I understand the question . you mean you want to show all the cars that are audi, manual and red

Comment: give me 5 minutes

Comment: I mean like an audi that is manual and red shows one image. But if its black I would like it to show another. and then do the same for other cars.

Comment: @Duncher  Sorry about that, I had an appointment scheduled and had to leave without notice. I understand your question and I'm working on it.

Comment: ok, I edited my answer, but you have to do a lot of manual work. for now it is only working for `Audi - Automatic - black and blue`, You can do the same for the rest of the cars too.

Comment: I have included some points in my answer, that you should go through. also please don't forget to accept the answer as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Just one last thing. Where do I apply max-width to limit the size of the pictures?

Comment: add the css to `img.showImg`. like this `img.showImg{max-width:150px;}`

Comment: Thanks for the help